# Is it possible to interact with Select2 components using HPE Unified Functional Testing?

Tags: hp-uft

I hope this question makes sense.

When recording in HPE UFT in my web application and selecting an option from a dropdown box made using [Select2](https://select2.org/) and then running the test it fails.

It returns the next error:

Cannot identify the object "WebElement" (of class WebElement).
Verify that this object's properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

This is for version 14.03 of the tool running in a Windows machine.

And I have tried different record modes without any luck.

The code that is generated when recording the test is:

```
Browser("LHO DEV").Page("SITE DEV_4").WebList("WebElement").Click

Browser("LHO DEV").Page("SITE DEV_4").WebTree("select2-single-results").Select "Option Value 9"

Browser("LHO DEV").Page("SITE DEV_4").WebEdit("WebEdit").Set "Value 9"
```

I understand that this code won't work as Select2 as it behaves in a different way than a regular dropdown/select box.

So, I would really appreciate if anyone can give me a  light in the right direction.

Comment: you've gotta show/analyze some HTML Code. At the end of the day most of the HTML widgets are a very complex combination of basic HTML elements and UI automation Software are just APIs to navigate that complexity a little bit easier :)

Long Story Short: In its' essence, UFT can give you access to DOM elements, you need to "teach it" to recognize structure

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found a solution maybe not the desired one but at least works.

Basically, the method **RunScript** allows executing Javascript, in this way I was able to access the Select2 element and select the desired values.

Here is the code I used:

```
Browser("LHO DEV").Page("SITE DEV_4").RunScript("$('#single').select2('open')")
Browser("LHO DEV").Page("SITE DEV_4").RunScript("$('#single_element').val([66]).trigger('change')")
Browser("LHO DEV").Page("SITE DEV_4").RunScript("$('#single_element').select2('close')")
```

I hope anyone finds this useful in the future.